Function returning NULL C
I am solving the "Permutation Sequence" problem in Leetcode with language C. I solved it with passing a reference of an array to a function, the function is modifying the array and returning something else. I am able to print the result in the main function, although it shows unidentified symbols after it and when I return it, it is showing NULL.
int Permutationsolver(char *s, int n, int k, bool * present, int count, int gen){
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(!present[i]){
            char c = i+49;
            present[i]=true;
            if(gen!=n-1){
                count = Permutationsolver(s, n, k, present, count, gen+1);
                if(count==k){
                    s[gen]=c;
                    printf("%c",c);
                    return count;
                }
            }
            else{
                count++;
                printf("%d\n", count);
                if(count==k){
                    s[gen]=c;
                    printf("%c",c);
                    return count;
                }
            }
            present[i]=false;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
char* getPermutation(int n, int k) {
    char s[n];
    bool present[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        present[i]=false;
    }
    char count = Permutationsolver(s, n, k, present, 0, 0);
    printf("\nnumber: %s", s);
    return s;
}

Here getPermutation is the main function, and when I print s, I am getting "213"(Here n=3 and k=3) what am I doing wrong here?

getPermutation is returning the address of a local variable which no longer exists after the function returns.  Never do that.

Then what to do?

Dynamic allocation would be one way. You also need to null terminate s before printing it. Example

Alternately, make s a parameter to getPermutation and have the caller allocate it (either on the stack, or the heap): char *getPermutation(char *s, int n, int k) {...
